# Byte counting in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I am making a word count, more specifically btye count for my text editor. However, I'm making it so that it counts Korean as well (as 2 bytes).

But I need to make it so that it does not count characters such as ` # = { } ( ) etc...

I've gotten this far, but I do not know how to get further from here. Right now it does everything but what I want it to do. Thank you!

```
    var limit_length = 1000;
    var msg_length = 0;
     
    //String bytes() Function
    String.prototype.bytes = function() {
        var msg = this;
        var cnt = 0;
     
        //Korean 2, English 1 count increment
        for( var i=0; i< msg.length; i++) 
            cnt += (msg.charCodeAt(i) > 128 ) ? 2 : 1;  
            return cnt;
        }

        //#submit-content Key up activation
        $("#submit-content").keyup(function( e ){
            msg_length = $.trim($(this).val()).bytes(); //to trim whitespaces 
         
            if( msg_length <= limit_length ) {     
                $("#type_num").css("color", "#474646");    
                $("#type_num").html( msg_length );  
            }
            else {
                $("#type_num").css("color", "#E55451");   
                $("#type_num").html( msg_length );   
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a string holding all characters you don't want to match in the count and compare each char to it:

```
var exceptString = "#={}()";

//Korean 2, English 1 count increment
    for( var i=0; i< msg.length; i++){
        if( exceptString.indexOf(msg.charAt(i)) == -1 ){ 
            cnt += (msg.charCodeAt(i) > 128 ) ? 2 : 1; 
        }
     }
     return cnt;
```

Comment: Where do need the count to disregard those characters?

Comment: basically whenver keyUp is activated in ```#submit-content``` textarea, msg_length value will be showed in ```#type_num```. I did not really understand what you meant by Where do need the count to disregard those characters? In my logic, I guess ``` for( var i=0; i< msg.length; i++) 
            cnt += (msg.charCodeAt(i) > 128 ) ? 2 : 1;  
            return cnt;
        }```

Comment: @SangYooKim I've edited the answer to show where the check should be placed. That way you only count the wanted characters

Comment: Thank you for your dedication to my question! I really appreciate it. The only problem is, it 'sort-of' works. It will count the strings sometimes.. Is there a regex way to exclude the special characters? It necessarily doesn't have to be ```#={}()```. It actually has to be all special characters...

Comment: @SangYooKim It really depends on exactly what you need. You can find information about regex codes here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 0):

A very short trick or work-around, name this solution how you want:

```
function lengthBytes(str) {
    return unescape(encodeURIComponent(str)).length;
}

// also you can add this solution to the String prototype
String.prototype.lengthBytes = function () {
    return unescape(encodeURIComponent(this)).length;
}
```

how it works

```
unescape(encodeURIComponent("§")).length;

// it will be encodeURIComponent("§") » %C2%A7

// and unescape("%C2%A7") will return 2 converted chars
```

Comment: just add first section of code, that define functionality, and use it as:
... $('#mydiv').text().lengthBytes .... OR .... lengthBytes($('#mydiv').text())

Comment: This soluttion is betters because are special chars encoded anso in 3 bytes,
thanks in advance for your feedback